# Does "for the record" come from legislatures' us(ag)e of the term?

Tags: etymology, american-english, speech

So, what you'll hear sometimes is people saying, "for the record" before they say what they're going to say. Now, I know that in Congress and other similar institutions around the world (including in courts of law), a variety of people will say, "for the record", due to there actually being a record of everything that's said. Sometimes they go "off the record", another common saying. So, my question is: do the sayings (in America), "for the record" & "off the record", originate from the halls of Congress?

Comment: The expression is used in the UK too, so it certainly doesn't refer specifically to the US Congress.

Comment: I would say it's probably based on official sessions and meetings as you propose; could be in parliament, courts of law, or others.

Comment: Yes, obviously it comes from the practice of using the phrase in formal meetings. Is there any reason to doubt that?

Answer (score 0):

**For the record** and similar uses (**on the record**, **let the record show**) emerged from contexts like legislatures or courtrooms where records of proceedings are kept. Consult especially this meaning within the Oxford English Dictionary entry for "[record, n.1 and adj.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/159867)":

> A. n.1
>
> I.Senses relating to the documentation or recording of facts, events, etc.
>
> 1. Law. The fact or condition of being, or of having been, written down as evidence of a legal matter, esp. as part of the proceedings or verdict of a court of law; evidence which is preserved in this way, and may be appealed to in case of dispute. Chiefly in phrases with prepositions, as of record, †in record, by record, on record, upon record.

While **for the record** attained its generalized use in the 20th century according to the same entry, the phrasing would have been familiar within legal contexts for centuries. For instance, take this excerpt from *[The Southwestern Reporter](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Southwestern_Reporter/8QDDG09uhNEC?hl=en&gbpv=1)* (Volume 105, 1908), where the judge enters a matter of fact into the record for a case about race in jury selection:

> Judge: I am willing **for the record** to show two years, if you want to. I will **let the record show** in that same connection that in the past seven or eight years, I do not remember how far back, but as far back as when Will King was indicted, that there have been several members of that race drawn, both on the grand jury and on the petit jury, but for the past two years there has not been. **The record may show** that affirmatively. You might state that the state agrees that those are the facts.

Uses of *the record* are quite common throughout the whole volume. Brief searches of other corpuses turn up similar results going centuries back.

The earliest usage I can find in English is in a 16th century legal text, *[In this booke is contayned the offices of shyriffes, bayliffes of lybertyes, escheatours, constables, and coroners [...]](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A00880.0001.001/1:6.1?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=for%20the%20record)*, by Anthony Fitzherbert and Gabriel Harvey, printed by Thomas Marsh not after 1579. **For the record** refers to admitting evidence from the coroner when it contradicts evidence from testimony before a circuit judge:

> Note that a presentmēt made before Iu∣sticers in Eire of a thing which is contrary
> to that that is entred in the Coroners rolle shalbe taken vayd, & the Coroners roll shall be taken **for the record**.

Comment: The question makes it explicit that the OP already knows about the use of such phrases in formal proceedings. What the question is about is the **connection** between the literal meanings of these phrases and their colloquial use in the settings in which no actual records are kept.

Comment: @jsw29 Yes, the connection is about the connection between literal usage and figurative use, and specifically OP's guess that the use in the US comes from a single place. Establishing that these proceedings were highly widespread and the usage goes back a long time helps establish that no one institution (like the US Congress) served as the origin for its more colloquial use.